# Rails SequencedHash source file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am testing AlumniOnRails (http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=2959&release_id=17170) which is based on Rails 1.2.6 (I know it's outdated) and managed to get it up, installed the required gems, created and migrated the data and most of the basic alumni functionalities are up but one, the part that is broken seems to be missing a library and yet I can't seem to find it after a few reasonable searches.

The logger shows *no such file to load -- collections/sequenced_hash* with a line within the controller having the code of *require 'collections/sequenced_hash* which is quite obvious that the *sequence_hash* library is missing.

A few searches on Google shows a few references, one with the closest pointer is http://collections.rubyforge.org/classes/SequencedHash.html but unfortuntely the source link is dead. Does anyone keep this kind of old file or point me to somewhere it is? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody answered this over ruby forum and it works:

> **gem install collections**